# Prove the uniform convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a monotonic sequence convergent to a. Let f : R $\to$ R be a continous and monotonic function. Then we define a series of functions as follows : $$f_n(x) := f(x+a_n)$$
Prove that the series is convergent on any interval $[-M,M] \in R$

**Atempt**

If $a_n$ is monotonic and convergent then it is decreasing. Thus we have $a_n > a_{n+1}   \forall{n}\in N $. Assume that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing (I'm not sure whether its legal to say it's not increasing). Then we have $f_1 \le f_2 \le f_3 \le ... \le f_n \le ... $. Last step : $f_n(x) \to f(x+a) $ pointwise as $n \to \infty$ .

My problem is I don't know how to use the information that we're dealing with a closed interval $[-M,M]$ or actually why we need to use to make the statements above. Especially I have trouble understanding why does the pointwise convergence take place in closed interval in this case.

Last but not least - if we added the closed interval condition to all the statements above we would conclude that the series converged uniformly thanks to Dini theorem. I would be really grateful if you could tell me how to plug it in :)

Comment: Note that $a_n = 1 - (1/n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence converging to $1$.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked it. Still it does not help me :(

Comment: RIght.  The point is that your assertion that a monotonic convergent sequence is decreasing is incorrect.  Nice problem, though, ***+1!***

Comment: I suppose the assumption that $a_n$ is decreasing or increasing is needed so as to say what's the behaviour of $f_n(x)$. But can we make one? If $f_n(x)$ is not decreasing my partial solution is totally wrecked

Comment: Don't have any answers yet . . . thinking . . . ;-)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated :)